# Calling Methods Inside Another Method In a Different Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I am having a difficult time trying to figure out the correct way on how to call methods inside a method that happens to be in a different class.

Here's my code:

runner,py

```
import reader as bb



class monitorRunner():

  def __init__(self):
    self.url = sys.argv[1]
    self.store = None
  
  def executeLink(self):
    self.determineStore()
    bb.BestBuyMonitor.executeBestBuyMonitor(self,self.url,self.store)

  def determineStore(self):

    -code-
  

if __name__== "__main__":
    taskMaster =  monitorRunner()
    taskMaster.executeLink()
```

reader.py

```
class BestBuyMonitor():

  def __init__(self):
    -variables-


  def executeBestBuyMonitor(self,store,url):
    self.getAPiData()
  
  def getAPiData(self):
    -code-
```

Trace:

```
self.getAPiData()
AttributeError: 'monitorRunner' object has no attribute 'getAPiData'
```

Not quite sure how to fix this, any help would be appriciated.

Comment: You must instantiate the class! `BestBuyMonitor().executeBestBuyMonitor(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `instantiating` the class. Use `()` after class's name:

```
import reader as bb



class monitorRunner():

  def __init__(self):
    self.url = sys.argv[1]
    self.store = None
  
  def executeLink(self):
    self.determineStore()
    bb.BestBuyMonitor().executeBestBuyMonitor(self.store,self.url)

  def determineStore(self):

    -code-
  

if __name__== "__main__":
    taskMaster =  monitorRunner()
    taskMaster.executeLink()
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, once doing this change it returns as `TypeError: executeBestBuyMonitor() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`..

Comment: Check my updated answer. Remove `self` from `executeBestBuyMonitor()`.